# BibTeX help with character escapes in book title

Tags: math-mode, bibliographies, bibtex

I am trying to write this

```
title = {c:\wp\file.txt\_05:41\_10-07-98},
```

as the title of a book in BibTeX except that it enters into math mode when I put it in like that using `\`.  I tried `\textbackslash` but it ended up in a similar mode.  Any thoughts?

EDIT

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{baskervald}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{references = {Works Cited}}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{primary}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{microtype}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

file.bib

```
@incollection {taylor2000,
author = {Gary Taylor},
title = {c:\wp\file.txt\_05:41\_10-07-98},
crossref = {murphy2000},
pages = {44-54},
}
@book {murphy2000,
editor = {Andrew Murphy},
title = {The Renaissance Text: Theory, Editing, Textuality},
publisher = {Great Britain: Manchester University Press},
year = {2000},
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With

```
title={\verb|c:\wp\file.txt_05:41_10-07-98|},
```

there should be no problem, if you use normal BibTeX styles. With `biblatex` based bibliography styles the thing is different, because the title will always be the argument to a command and so `\verb` will not work.

The simplest way out is to input that "title" as

```
title = {\texttt{c:\textbackslash wp\textbackslash file.txt\_05:41\_10-07-98}},
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought it worked but it did not.  What do you think?

Comment: @Wrigley242 Without a real example it's very difficult to give more help.

Comment: I put the example above.  That is the exact phrase but I am not sure how to write it out.  \verb sent off another error when I used it so I am trying to work around it.

Comment: @Wrigley242 Sorry, but that's *not* an example. It's impossible to guess what you're using: document class, packages, bibliography manager (BibTeX or `biblatex`) and many other details.

Comment: Sorry! I added it above.  Let me know if any of that helps.  Thanks

Comment: @Wrigley242 We can't guess your bibliography file. Show only one entry that produces the problem.

Comment: I put up the one I think is the problem.  thanks

Comment: Thank you for your help, I figured it out.  All I needed was the \usepackage{url}.  Now it works perfectly with no errors.  Thank you.